How to change an ogr2ogr KML Placemark Name?
If I use
ogr2ogr -f LIBKML m32540000.parcel.kml ../../3254.kml -ct \
'+proj=affine +xoff=-.00005 +yoff=-0.00004' \
-nln land -clipdst mChopper.kml -clipdstlayer mChopper \
-clipdstwhere "Name = 'CHOPPER_32540000'" \
-sql 'SELECT Name FROM "3254"'

I get this KML,
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
  <Document id="root_doc">
    <Document id="land">
      <name>land</name>
      <Placemark id="land.1">
        <name>3254-0 地號</name>
        <Polygon>
          <outerBoundaryIs>
            <LinearRing>
              <coordinates>
                120.866241,24.1815623333333,0...

How can I change that second
        <name>3254-0 地號</name>

field to
        <name>Something else</name>

without resorting to sed, awk, perl, etc.?
I only want this one line to change.
No I don't want to trigger SimpleData,
swelling my file.
I am hoping all I need to do is adjust the
-sql 'SELECT Name FROM "3254"'

line. I changed the first <name> field via -nln,
now how about the second?
Note my output consists of only one "SQL row",
so it would be fine if I changed "all the rows" to the same value.
Alas,
-sql 'SELECT 22 AS Name FROM "3254"'

Just removes the <name> tag and creates SimpleData.
